# apache-camel file component recursive and tempFileName

Tags: apache-camel

I have the following problem:
I would like to use ftp component to read and then write files along with paths relative to ftp user home directory. For that I use recursive=true in spring and it works fine. The problem is that I also need to use tempFileName but in the target location *tmp files created as ${file:onlyname.noext}.tmp cannot be stored in the target directory but in home direcotry i.e.
when source is:

```
A
|-> B
|-> C
    |->file.txt
```

the target should be:

```
A
|->file.tmp (temporary)
|-> C
    |->file.txt (file.tmp cannot be stored here!)
```

However, tempFileName seems to be only working relative to full path. Can this be changed?

Comment: Try setting `tempFileName=../${file:onlyname.noext}`. And see more details in the file-language: http://camel.apache.org/file-language.html

Comment: Hi Claus. Thank you for your answer. This is indeed the first thing I did however it does not work. File language works fine but the problem is that './' is alwaya relative to file full name i.e. including its path as recursive is set true. As an example if recursive file name is 'a/file.txt' then your attempt would give tempFileName = 'a/../file' which gives an error.

Comment: Yeah but its frankly crap to store temp files in another folder. Save the file with a .tmp prefix and rename when done.

Comment: I totally agree with you but the fact is that an application consuming files placed with camel cannot distinguish suffixes and consumes everything. It's crap yet cannot be changed. So far I used camel to deal with such crap yet this this time it is probably too much crap to deal with. Anyways, thanks for help.

Comment: I logged a ticket as there is room for improvement to compact that .. path: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10737

Comment: Is it a requirement that the temp-file be named file.tmp instead of file.txt?

Comment: @noMad17 - no, it just has to have different name than original file, obviously. *.tmp just seems a good idea for a temp file:)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this today, but we have an improvement so you will be able to do this in Camel 2.18.2 onwards. Then you can use `../${file:onlyname.noext}.tmp` as the temporary file name.

This was logged in ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10737

Answer (score 0):

Since the .tmp suffix was not a requirement I suggest looking at the tempPrefix-option.

```
<to uri="file:///C?tempPrefix="../" />
```

This would then lead to your file being stored in directory A with the name file.txt until the whole file has been completely written, then it will be moved to the final destination of directory C.